# Get current status of a delayed job in Sidekiq (through Active Job?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I use rails 4.2.5 and Sidekiq for background processing.

There is an API which an application can call.

I now have this code:

```
def start_item(name, init_query)
  job_id = AzureBufferBase.delay.execute_in_transaction(name, init_query)
  job_id
end
```

I get a job_id back like this: ef95bdd9cf5da0ef1273db6c

Now I want to expose this status through the API:

```
module Api
  class BackgroundJobsController < BaseApiController
    def show
      result = Sidekiq::Status(params[:id])
      render json: { 'status' => result.to_json }, status: 200
    end
  end
end
```

Sidekiq::Status: this doesn't work, but my question is, how can I get the status from Active Job of a job (queued, progress, completed, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for [Active Job Status](https://github.com/cdale77/active_job_status) gem.